# msys2: not finding windows programs despite (MSYS2_PATH_TYPE = inherit)

Tags: windows, environment-variables, mingw-w64, msys2

Using MSYS2 64-bit version 20161025 on Windows 10...

I'm unable to get msys2 to recognize programs in the windows path.  For example, after installing Go version 1.8.3 using the windows the installer: (1) Cygwin finds go.exe (2) the Windows command prompt finds go.exe but (3) MSYS2 does not.

Please refer to attached image.  Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Don't post images for this purpose. Text takes less time to read

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 36):

Run `msys2_shell.cmd -use-full-path`

or

uncomment `MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit` `in msys2.ini` (can be found in the installation directory of MSYS2).

---

[Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2140) regarding the `inherit` flag.

Comment: `msys2_shell.cmd -use-full-path` works for me but `MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit` not.

Comment: same for me, `MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit` does not work for me

Comment: uncommenting `MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit` in `mingw64.ini` worked for me when running `mingw64.exe`. I would assume the same would apply for `mingw32.ini` and `msys2.ini` depending on which executable you are running.

Comment: If using conemu/cmder you may need to set variable in call. Nothing else worked until I added `& set MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit` under Startup -> Tasks -> Msys2-64 -> Commands

Answer (score 2):

I just added the paths I wanted to access from Msys2 into the `.bash_profile` file in `home/{my user name}/`. That works. I just used Notepad++ in Windows to edit, but you can use nano or vim as well.

I couldn't get the "inherit" in the .ini file to work, or the msys2 shell cmd (which opened another terminal window with the same path as what I started out with) to work either.

I didn't really want the whole Windows path anyway, it has the bin folder for Git for Windows (a crippled MingW64 build) and I thought weird stuff might happen.

The file looks looks like this:

```
# User dependent .bash_profile file

# source the users bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi

# Add Coretto Java 11 and Windows Python to path
PATH="${PATH}:/c/batch:/c/Program Files/Python310/Scripts/:/c/Program Files/Python310/:/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.16_9/bin"
```

Remember to change `C:\` to `/c/` and all backslashes to forward slashes. Use colons to separate paths, not semicolons. Surround the path with quotes. Use `${PATH}` to keep the existing path to all those `/bin/` directories. Spaces in the directory names are fine.

Here is what I get in the Msys2 terminal:

```
StephanPeters@Stephan-HPZBook15G4-Y4E78AV MSYS ~
# java --version
openjdk 11.0.16.1 2022-08-12 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.16.9.1 (build 11.0.16.1+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.16.9.1 (build 11.0.16.1+9-LTS, mixed mode)

StephanPeters@Stephan-HPZBook15G4-Y4E78AV MSYS ~
# which java
/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.16_9/bin/java

StephanPeters@Stephan-HPZBook15G4-Y4E78AV MSYS ~
#
```

[Path in use: Msys2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNMxs.png)

Comment: I did exactly the same since I don(t want the whole Windows %PATH% in my msys2 $PATH - in my situation I needed to add /c/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm

Answer (score 1):

You must uncomment `MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit` specifically for the configuration file of the environment you're using.

For example, if you're using the UCRT64 environment, you must uncomment `MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit` in the `ucrt64.ini` file instead of `msys2.ini`.